# How to have an exception to URL routing in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I have some legacy code that needs to be used in a new application. I would like to write the new application in CodeIgniter, but I still need to have some way of accessing the old code. what I would like to do is have an exception in the routing so that any url that has the format of `example.com/old_stuff/*` goes to an `old_stuff` folder, and acts as a regular, un-routed applications, while any other url such as `example.com/new_stuff` would route to a `new_stuff` controller, for example. So essentially what I want it to have URLs behave as they usually would in CodeIgniter, with the exception of any that start with one certain string.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

place codeigniter at your web root, and have your folder `old_stuff` in the web root also.

then use .htaccess with these rules (assuming you have mod_rewrite)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|old_stuff|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

then, a uri beginning with `old_stuff` will just serve up the content bypassing codeigniter.

Comment: i'm not sure i'm following. new_stuff was just one example controller.  there could be several. I edited the question to make it a bit clearer.